# Mathematically explaining a trapped surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, surfaces

I'm currently writing my thesis, and the general area is that of minimal surfaces. I have a deep interest in cosmology so I have directed it towards space-time, i.e. applying minimal surfaces in space, such as apparent horizons, etc. I am now approaching horizons as trapped surfaces, and although I understand what a trapped surface geometrically is, I'm having a great deal of trouble understanding the maths behind it. (I need to keep reminding myself that this is a maths thesis NOT a physics one)

If anyone could help clarify or explain to me (as simply as possible) the maths behind it, I would be extremely grateful!

Thanks :-)

Sarah